# How can i call the BufferGeometryUtils from threejs?

Tags: three.js

I tried to merge two geometries pre-loaded from two PLY files, the console of the browser told me should be use the `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries()` for merge de two geometries into one, but I some problems for call this from the class.

Here is my code:

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
    var singleGeometry, material, mesh;
    var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();

    function loadPLY(path) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        loader.load(path, result => {
           console.log('Success');
            resolve(result);
        });
     });

     }

    init();

   Promise.all([
     loadPLY("ply/Paso_1_mandible.ply"),
     loadPLY("ply/maxila.ply")
   ])
   .then(geometries => {
      geometries.forEach(geometry => geometry.computeVertexNormals());
        singleGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        singleGeometry = THREE.BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);   

     material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0055ff });
     mesh = new THREE.Mesh(singleGeometry, material);

     mesh.position.y = 1;
     mesh.position.z =  1;
     mesh.position.x = 1;
     mesh.scale.multiplyScalar( 0.0001 );
     mesh.castShadow = true;
     mesh.receiveShadow = true;


    scene.add(mesh);


    })
     .then(() => {
        animate();
    })
    .catch(err => {console.error(err);});
```

but I got this error:

```
TypeError: "THREE.BufferGeometryUtils is undefined"
```

here is the link to the documentation:

[class BufferGeometryUtils](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries)

Comment: anybody? please :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in examples/js/BufferGeometryUtils.js in the THREE master distro.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip

Comment: If Typescript throw error `Could not find a declaration file for module 'three/examples/js/utils/BufferGeometryUtils'`, just change `js` to `jsm` in the path, like that `three/examples/jsm/utils/BufferGeometryUtils`

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: "THREE.BufferGeometryUtils is undefined"` is quite clear.

You need to include the `BufferGeometryUtils` class / file in your code.
As it is in the examples folder, it is not included in the main Three.js library.